# Swiftly turning wheels – The May 2017 Community Challenge

Tags: swift, community-challenge, sprite-kit

This is my attempt at the [May 2017 Community Challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/may-2017-community-challenge/7264#7264) in Swift, with a chain consisting of rigid links.

I took this as an opportunity to learn [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/spritekit/), Apple's framework for 2D games. At least Xcode 8.3.2 with Swift 3 is required to compile the code. It runs on *both macOS and iOS* (instructions below).

**VectorUtils.swift** – Some helper methods for vector calculations.

```swift
import CoreGraphics

let π = CGFloat.pi

extension CGVector {

    init(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) {
        self.init(dx: to.x - from.x, dy: to.y - from.y)
    }
    
    func cross(_ other: CGVector) -> CGFloat {
        return dx * other.dy - dy * other.dx
    }
    
    var length: CGFloat {
        return hypot(dx, dy)
    }
    
    var arg: CGFloat {
        return atan2(dy, dx)
    }
}
```

**Sprocket.swift** – The type describing a single sprocket.

```swift
import CoreGraphics

struct Sprocket {
    let center: CGPoint
    let radius: CGFloat
    let teeth: Int
    
    var clockwise: Bool!
    var prevAngle: CGFloat!
    var nextAngle: CGFloat!
    var prevPoint: CGPoint!
    var nextPoint: CGPoint!
    
    init(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) {
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius
        self.teeth = Int((radius/2).rounded())
    }
    
    init(_ triplet: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, r: CGFloat)) {
        self.init(center: CGPoint(x: triplet.x, y: triplet.y), radius: triplet.r)
    }
    
    // Normalize angles such that
    //     0 <= prevAngle < 2π
    // and
    //     prevAngle <= nextAngle < prevAngle + 2π  (if rotating counter-clockwise)
    //     prevAngle - 2π < nextAngle <= prevAngle  (if rotating clockwise)
    mutating func normalizeAngles() {
        prevAngle = prevAngle.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2 * π)
        nextAngle = nextAngle.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2 * π)
        while prevAngle < 0 {
            prevAngle = prevAngle + 2 * π
        }
        if clockwise {
            while nextAngle > prevAngle {
                nextAngle = nextAngle - 2 * π
            }
        } else {
            while nextAngle < prevAngle {
                nextAngle = nextAngle + 2 * π
            }
        }
    }
    
    mutating func computeTangentPoints() {
        prevPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x + radius * cos(prevAngle),
                            y: center.y + radius * sin(prevAngle))
        nextPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x + radius * cos(nextAngle),
                            y: center.y + radius * sin(nextAngle))
    }
}
```

**ChainDrive.swift** - The type describing the complete chain drive
system. Also contains the code to compute rotation directions,
tangent angles/points, and the length of the various segments of the
chain.

```swift
import CoreGraphics

struct ChainDrive {
    
    var sprockets: [Sprocket]
    
    var length: CGFloat!
    var period: CGFloat!
    var linkCount: Int!
    var accumLength: [(CGFloat, CGFloat)]!
    
    init(sprockets: [Sprocket]) {
        self.sprockets = sprockets
        
        computeSprocketData()
        computeChainLength()
    }
    
    init(_ triplets: [(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat)]) {
        self.init(sprockets: triplets.map(Sprocket.init))
    }
    
    mutating func computeSprocketData() {
        
        // Compute rotation directions:
        for i in 0..<sprockets.count {
            let j = (i + 1) % sprockets.count
            let k = (j + 1) % sprockets.count
            
            let v1 = CGVector(from: sprockets[j].center, to: sprockets[i].center)
            let v2 = CGVector(from: sprockets[j].center, to: sprockets[k].center)
            sprockets[j].clockwise = v1.cross(v2) > 0
        }
        if !sprockets[0].clockwise {
            sprockets[1..<sprockets.count].reverse()
            for i in 0..<sprockets.count {
                sprockets[i].clockwise = !sprockets[i].clockwise
            }
        }
        
        // Compute tangent angles:
        for i in 0..<sprockets.count {
            let j = (i + 1) % sprockets.count
            
            let v = CGVector(from: sprockets[i].center, to: sprockets[j].center)
            let d = v.length
            let a = v.arg
            if sprockets[i].clockwise == sprockets[j].clockwise {
                var phi = acos((sprockets[i].radius - sprockets[j].radius)/d)
                if !sprockets[i].clockwise {
                    phi = -phi
                }
                sprockets[i].nextAngle = a + phi
                sprockets[j].prevAngle = a + phi
            } else {
                var phi = acos((sprockets[i].radius + sprockets[j].radius)/d)
                if !sprockets[i].clockwise {
                    phi = -phi
                }
                sprockets[i].nextAngle = a + phi
                sprockets[j].prevAngle = a + phi - π
            }
        }
        
        // Normalize angles and compute tangent points:
        for i in 0..<sprockets.count {
            sprockets[i].normalizeAngles()
            sprockets[i].computeTangentPoints()
        }
    }
    
    mutating func computeChainLength() {
        accumLength = []
        length = 0
        for i in 0..<sprockets.count {
            let j = (i + 1) % sprockets.count
            let l1 = length + abs(sprockets[i].nextAngle - sprockets[i].prevAngle) * sprockets[i].radius
            let l2 = l1 + CGVector(from: sprockets[i].nextPoint, to: sprockets[j].prevPoint).length
            accumLength.append((l1, l2))
            length = l2
        }
        
        let count = Int(length / (4 * π))
        let p1 = length / CGFloat(count)
        let p2 = length / CGFloat(count + 1)
        if abs(p1 - 4 * π) <= abs(p2 - 4 * π) {
            period = p1
            linkCount = count
        } else {
            period = p2
            linkCount = count + 1
        }
        
    }
    
    func linkCoordinatesAndPhases(offset: CGFloat) -> ([CGPoint], [CGFloat]) {
        var coords: [CGPoint] = []
        var phases: [CGFloat] = []
        var offset = offset
        var total = offset
        var i = 0

        repeat {
            let j = (i + 1) % sprockets.count
            let s: CGFloat = sprockets[i].clockwise ? -1 : 1
            
            var phi = sprockets[i].prevAngle + s*offset / sprockets[i].radius
            phases.append(phi)
            while total <= accumLength[i].0 && coords.count < linkCount {
                coords.append(CGPoint(x: sprockets[i].center.x + cos(phi) * sprockets[i].radius,
                                      y: sprockets[i].center.y + sin(phi) * sprockets[i].radius))
                phi += s * period / sprockets[i].radius
                total += period
            }
            
            var d = total - accumLength[i].0
            let v = CGVector(from: sprockets[i].nextPoint, to: sprockets[j].prevPoint)
            while total <= accumLength[i].1 && coords.count < linkCount {
                coords.append(CGPoint(x: sprockets[i].nextPoint.x + d * v.dx / v.length,
                                      y: sprockets[i].nextPoint.y + d * v.dy / v.length))
                d += period
                total += period
            }
            
            offset = total - accumLength[i].1
            i = j
        } while coords.count < linkCount

        return (coords, phases)
    }
    
}
```

**SprocketNode.swift** – Defines a `SKShapeNode` subclass for drawing
a single sprocket.

```swift
import SpriteKit

class SprocketNode: SKShapeNode {
    let radius: CGFloat
    let clockwise: Bool
    let teeth: Int
    
    init(sprocket: Sprocket) {
        self.radius = sprocket.radius
        self.clockwise = sprocket.clockwise
        self.teeth = sprocket.teeth
        super.init()
        
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: radius - 2, y: 0))
        for i in 0..<teeth {
            let a1 = π * CGFloat(4 * i - 1)/CGFloat(2 * teeth)
            let a2 = π * CGFloat(4 * i + 1)/CGFloat(2 * teeth)
            let a3 = π * CGFloat(4 * i + 3)/CGFloat(2 * teeth)
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint.zero, radius: radius - 2,
                        startAngle: a1, endAngle: a2, clockwise: false)
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint.zero, radius: radius + 2,
                        startAngle: a2, endAngle: a3, clockwise: false)
        }
        path.closeSubpath()
        self.path = path
        
        self.lineWidth = 0
        self.fillColor = SKColor(red: 0x86/255, green: 0x84/255, blue: 0x81/255, alpha: 1) // #868481
        self.strokeColor = .clear
        self.position = sprocket.center
        
        do {
            let path = CGMutablePath()
            path.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: -3, y: -3, width: 6, height: 6))
            path.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: -radius + 4.5, y: -radius + 4.5,
                                       width: 2 * radius - 9, height: 2 * radius - 9))
            let node = SKShapeNode(path: path)
            node.fillColor = SKColor(red: 0x64/255, green: 0x63/255, blue: 0x61/255, alpha: 1) // #646361
            node.lineWidth = 0
            node.strokeColor = .clear
            self.addChild(node)
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**LinkNode.swift** – Defines a `SKShapeNode` subclass for drawing
a chain link.

```swift
import SpriteKit

class LinkNode: SKShapeNode {
    static let narrowWidth: CGFloat = 2
    static let wideWidth : CGFloat = 6
    
    let pitch: CGFloat
    
    init(pitch: CGFloat) {
        self.pitch = pitch
        super.init()
        
        let phi = asin(LinkNode.narrowWidth / LinkNode.wideWidth)
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: -pitch/2, y: 0), radius: LinkNode.wideWidth/2,
                    startAngle: phi, endAngle: 2 * π - phi, clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pitch/2, y: -LinkNode.narrowWidth/2))
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: pitch/2, y: 0), radius: LinkNode.narrowWidth/2,
                    startAngle: -π/2, endAngle: π/2, clockwise: false)
        path.closeSubpath()
        self.path = path
        self.fillColor = .black
        self.lineWidth = 0
        self.strokeColor = .clear
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func moveTo(leftPin: CGPoint, rightPin: CGPoint) {
        position = CGPoint(x: (leftPin.x + rightPin.x)/2,
                           y: (leftPin.y + rightPin.y)/2)
        zRotation = CGVector(from: leftPin, to: rightPin).arg
    }

}
```

**ChainDriveScene.swift** – Defines a `SKScene` subclass for drawing
and animating the chain drive.

```swift
import SpriteKit

typealias Triples = [(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat)]

// The system from the challenge: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7264 :
let system0: Triples = [(0, 0, 16), (100, 0, 16), (100, 100, 12), (50, 50, 24), (0, 100, 12)]

// Other systems from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64764:
let system1: Triples = [(0, 0, 26), (120, 0, 26)]
let system2: Triples = [(100, 100, 60), (220, 100, 14)]
let system3: Triples = [(100, 100, 16), (100, 0, 24), (0, 100, 24), (0, 0, 16)]
let system4: Triples = [(0, 0, 60), (44, 140, 16), (-204, 140, 16), (-160, 0, 60), (-112, 188, 12),
                      (-190, 300, 30), (30, 300, 30), (-48, 188, 12)]
let system5: Triples = [(0, 128, 14), (46.17, 63.55, 10), (121.74, 39.55, 14), (74.71, -24.28, 10),
                      (75.24, -103.55, 14), (0, -78.56, 10), (-75.24, -103.55, 14),
                      (-74.71, -24.28, 10), (-121.74, 39.55, 14), (-46.17, 63.55, 10)]
let system6: Triples = [(367, 151, 12), (210, 75, 36), (57, 286, 38), (14, 181, 32), (91, 124, 18),
                      (298, 366, 38), (141, 3, 52), (80, 179, 26), (313, 32, 26), (146, 280, 10),
                      (126, 253, 8), (220, 184, 24), (135, 332, 8), (365, 296, 50), (248, 217, 8),
                      (218, 392, 30)]

class ChainDriveScene: SKScene {
    
    let chainDrive: ChainDrive
    let chainSpeed = 16 * π // speed (points/sec)
    
    var initialTime: TimeInterval!
    var sprocketNodes: [SprocketNode] = []
    var linkNodes: [LinkNode] = []
    
    class func newScene() -> ChainDriveScene {
        let system = ChainDrive(system0)
        return ChainDriveScene(system: system)
    }
    
    init(system: ChainDrive) {
        self.chainDrive = system
        
        let minx = system.sprockets.map { $0.center.x - $0.radius }.min()! - 15
        let miny = system.sprockets.map { $0.center.y - $0.radius }.min()! - 15
        let maxx = system.sprockets.map { $0.center.x + $0.radius }.max()! + 15
        let maxy = system.sprockets.map { $0.center.y + $0.radius }.max()! + 15
        
        super.init(size: CGSize(width: maxx - minx, height: maxy - miny))
        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: -minx/(maxx - minx), y: -miny/(maxy - miny))
        self.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setUpScene() {
        
        backgroundColor = .white
        sprocketNodes = chainDrive.sprockets.map(SprocketNode.init)
        for node in sprocketNodes {
            self.addChild(node)
        }
        
        let (coords, _) = chainDrive.linkCoordinatesAndPhases(offset: 0)
        for i in 0..<coords.count {
            let j = (i + 1) % coords.count
            let node = LinkNode(pitch: chainDrive.period)
            node.moveTo(leftPin: coords[i], rightPin: coords[j])
            self.addChild(node)
            linkNodes.append(node)
        }
    }
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.setUpScene()
    }
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if initialTime == nil {
            initialTime = currentTime
        }
        
        let distance = CGFloat(currentTime - initialTime) * chainSpeed * speed
        let k = Int(distance/chainDrive.period) % linkNodes.count
        let offset = distance.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: chainDrive.period)
        
        let (coords, phases) = chainDrive.linkCoordinatesAndPhases(offset: offset)
        for i in 0..<linkNodes.count {
            let p1 = coords[i % coords.count]
            let p2 = coords[(i + 1) % coords.count]
            linkNodes[(i + linkNodes.count - k) % linkNodes.count].moveTo(leftPin: p1, rightPin: p2)
        }
        for i in 0..<phases.count {
            sprocketNodes[i].zRotation = phases[i]
        }
    }
}
```

The complete project is
[available on GitHub](https://github.com/martinr448/ChainDriveSystem).
Alternatively:

- In Xcode 8.3.2 (or later), create a new project from the "Cross-platform SpriteKit Game" template.
- Select "Include iOS Application" and/or "Include macOS Application".
- Add the above source files to the project.
- In the GameViewController.swift files, replace

  ```swift
    let scene = GameScene.newGameScene()
  ```

by

```swift
    let scene = ChainDriveScene.newScene()
```

- Compile and run!

The animation runs with approx 60 frames per second, both on a
1.2 GHz MacBook and on an iPhone 6s.
To give you a rough impression of what it looks like, I took a screen
recording with QuickTime Player and converted it to an animated GIF
with *ffmpeg* and *gifsicle*:

[image: Simple animated chain network, 5 gears]
[image: Complicated animated chain network, 16 gears]

All feedback is welcome, such as (but not limited to):

- Can the geometrical computations be simplified?
- Are there any better type/variable/function names?
- There are several "implicitly unwrapped optional" properties
  in `struct Sprocket`. The reason is that these are computed
  (in `func computeSprocketData()`) after all sprockets have been
  initialized. Any suggestions on how to do this two-step initialization
  more elegantly?
- Initially I used a `SKAction` for rotating the sprockets, but did not
  find a way to animate the chain with `SKActions`. Therefore both
  sprockets and chain links are now updated in the `update()` method
  (which is called for each frame). Is there a better way to achieve
  the same result?
- Another idea was to use `SKAction.followPath()` to animate the chain links.
  That worked well for *one* link, but I could not figure out how to make the
  other links follow the same path with a delay. Is that possible?
- This is my first SpriteKit project, therefore any advice on how to
  make more idiomatic use of that framework is appreciated.

Comment: @Linny: It was very nice of you to offer a bounty on this question. Unfortunately, it was as unsuccessful as the previous two bounties.

Comment: One has to try :).

Comment: I wonder... either we don't have enough experienced Swift people or everyone finds your code perfect.

Comment: No code is perfect. I don't see spaces around the `/` operator, for one :P

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Write a review some of us old timers will probably vote it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the fact that this has gone unanswered for quite some time is a testament to the quality of the code. It appears the code is separated well into individual files and indentation is consistent.

Some could argue that there should be more comments, though the code is somewhat self-documenting as methods are named appropriately. Some variable names are a bit overly brief - e.g. `var d` within **ChainDrive.swift** (in multiple functions). In some cases this is assigned to the difference between twonumbers - for example: in the `repeat` loop within `linkCoordinatesAndPhases()`

> ```
> var d = total - accumLength[i].0
> ```

and then in the sub-sequent `while` loop values are added to it:

> ```
> d += period
> ```

in other cases it is simply assigned to the length of a vector - e.g. in the loop within `computeSprocketData()`

> ```
> let v = CGVector(from: sprockets[i].center, to: sprockets[j].center)
> let d = v.length
> ```